# Powershell small numbers rounding up etc

Tags: powershell, math

How do i stop numbers being rounded up and changing in powershell for example

```
[int]$i = 0.0000085
```

showing as being 0 but i want to keep it as 0.0000085 so i can add and subtract the number etc.

Comment: You cast to an int. Don't use int or an appropriate data type

Comment: By definition an integer is a whole number. Use `[Double]` or `[Decimal]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Steven comment you are forcing the number to be an `integer` which by definition holds whole numbers only and that is why it's loose the precision, remove the cast for `int` and powershell will cast it automatically or cast to `decimal` instead, see an example:

```
$i = 0.0000085
$i
8.5E-06
$i.GetType().Name
Double

[int]$i = 0.0000085
$i
0
$i.GetType().Name
Int32

[decimal]$i = 0.0000085
$i
0.0000085
```

Also, if the number is not intend for any math operation, you can use string as well

```
$i = "0.0000085"
$i
0.0000085
```